# Creates output in debug, but not in release - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, csv, output

I have a VB Visual Studio 2012 Project where I create .csv files. Below is an excerpt from it. Basically, when I am debugging my program, it creates the .csv files in the bin/debug as expected. But I can't figure out for the life of me where or why it is not creating them when I publish the program. I have changed the build output path to a few different times and made sure I was on the 'Release' portion of it. I don't even care where the output is, I just want it somewhere! Thanks

EDIT: Okay so I found the file... C:\Users\ah0169569\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\BLWZBB1R.02J\XTOQVPX5.N3O\payr..tion_d‌​310a0976fa1c317_0001.0000_81024c9c62a3db84 
So that is a silly location. How can I change the output to be in my application folder? Or somewhere specified by the user?

```
Sub DataTable2CSV(ByVal table As DataTable, ByVal filename As String)
    DataTable2CSV(table, filename, ",")
End Sub
Sub DataTable2CSV(ByVal table As DataTable, ByVal filename As String, _
    ByVal sepChar As String)
    Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Try
        writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)

        ' first write a line with the columns name
        Dim sep As String = ""
        Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            builder.Append(sep).Append(col.ColumnName)
            sep = sepChar
        Next
        writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString())

        ' then write all the rows
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            sep = ""
            builder = New System.Text.StringBuilder

            For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
                builder.Append(sep).Append(row(col.ColumnName))
                sep = sepChar
            Next
            writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString())
        Next
    Finally
        If Not writer Is Nothing Then writer.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: if you are running the published app from something like "Program Files", you app probably does not have rights to create/read/change/delete files there. Change the output destination to a Users folder

Comment: Where are you calling the subroutine from? What are you passing in as `filename`?

Comment: Writing a try/catch in that way is an assured system to never know why your code doesn't work.

Comment: It is installed to a Users folder so I don't think thats it. I am passing filename as just a string to name the file.

Comment: I cleared all try/catch statements and still the same result

Comment: Have you tried giving it a full path in the filename? Otherwise, you could search your disk drive for the filename to see where it has ended up.

Comment: Okay! So I found the file..

Comment: C:\Users\ah0169569\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\BLWZBB1R.02J\XTOQVPX5.N3O\payr..tion_d310a0976fa1c317_0001.0000_81024c9c62a3db84

So that is a silly location. How can I change the output to be in my application folder? Or somewhere specified by the user?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to change in your code it the Try/Finally. In this way you will never know if your code fails and why it fails. I have added a Catch and a MessageBox just to show if there is an error

```
Try
    Using writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)

        Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            builder.Append(col.ColumnName + sepChar)
        Next
        builder.Length -= 1
        builder.AppendLine()

        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
                builder.Append(row(col.ColumnName) + sepChar)
            Next
            builder.Length -= 1
            builder.AppendLine()
        Next
        writer.Write(builder.ToString())
    End Using
 Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
 End Try
```

Next thing is the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) that ensure a proper closing of your Stream also in case of exceptions. 
Latest is a fix on your usage of StringBuilder to accumulate your text and write everything in just one call. Of course this is not a problem with small data.

Comment: I just deleted my try catch statement entirely and still am not receiving any errors.

Comment: I am using your code now as well and it is returning successful, but still no output. (I did change the + in line 13 to &)

Comment: I can't figure out what happening on your side. To be honest also the original code should work and I can only imagine a permission problem but a message box should be displayed. Try to put some messagebox displaying current values to check if the code is running as expected